# INSTALL PLUGIN 'rpl_semi_sync_master' SONAME 'semisync_master.so' not working

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to install semi synchronous replication in my mysql 5.5 and trying to execute the below command:

INSTALL PLUGIN 'rpl_semi_sync_master' SONAME 'semisync_master.so'

but this command is throwing the below error:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''rpl_semi_sync_master' SONAME 'semisync_master.so'' at line 1

Please help regarding this. We are using Win7 Professional SP1 32-bit OS.

Thank You

Comment: what is the names of ur .cc and .so file?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/install-plugin.html correct syntax is without apostrophes around plugin name:

```
 INSTALL PLUGIN rpl_semi_sync_master SONAME 'semisync_master.so'
```